# Unzip the file silently in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I checked many post here but could not find anything helpful.
If there is any, please direct me.
I am able to unzip the file but it is opening a pop up window which show the progress of unzipping. I want it to execute the steps silently.
below is my code:-

```
$filepath = Get-ChildItem -Path \\Srcfile\data -Filter *.zip -Recurse
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
foreach($file in $filepath)
{
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.FullName)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($file.DirectoryName).copyhere($item)
    }
    Remove-Item $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: You may use [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.3) instead of the Shell method  ....

Comment: Expand-Archive solved my problem, thanks

Comment: Hi @Olaf, could you please look at another question and suggest what to do in this case:-
Download file from SFTP server using powershell(Have a working script for FTP server)

Comment: I'd recommend to *NOT* re-invent the wheel again and use what others already came up with. Search the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=sftp) for *sftp* for something you can use right away or at least adapt to your particular needs.